# NetBeans 8.2 installer doesn't detect OpenJDK in folder on Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation

I've been trying to install Netbeans on Debian 9. I want to use the JDK that already comes with it. It's OpenJDK 8. But when I tell the installer to look into that folder for the JDK it says it doesn't have it.

[image]

However, if I direct the installer to the JDK I downloaded from Oracle, it seems to work as shown below.

[image]

This folder also doesn't work
[image]

What's causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve probably installed `openjdk-8-jre`, which installs `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` (on `amd64`) but only contains the JRE, not the full JDK. To install the JDK, you need to install the `openjdk-8-jdk` package too.

Comment: I edited the question because there is another folder that says JDK as well. And that one also doesn't work. I'm talking about the third screenshot. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, both those folders point to the same place (`java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` is a symlink to `java-8-openjdk-amd64`). I meant what I wrote, which is that you need to install the `openjdk-8-jdk` package.

Comment: Alright, the two folders were confusing at first. I installed the package you said and now it works. Thanks!